# Laravel unable to set foreign key to NULL

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-schema-builder

I am trying to set a foreign key to `null`, `deleted_by` does not allow me to save `null` as the default value.

I want to be able to set the `deleted_by` field to `null` when I create a product. I'm currently using a factory to generate the product but I am unable to seed my database as I can't set the field to `null`.

##### `Product` table

```php
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title', 2000);
    $table->string('slug', 2000);
    $table->string('image', 2000)->nullable();
    $table->string('image_mime')->nullable();
    $table->integer('image_size')->nullable();
    $table->longText('description')->nullable();
    $table->decimal('price', 10, 2);
    $table->foreignId('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')->nullable();
    $table->foreignId('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users')->nullable();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->foreignId('deleted_by')->references('id')->on('users')->nullable()->constrained();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

##### `User` table

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

##### `Product` factory

```php
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'title' => fake()->text(),
        'image' =>fake()->imageUrl(),
        'description' => fake()->realText(200),
        'price' => fake()->randomFloat(2, 2, 5),
        'created_at' => now(),
        'updated_at' => now(),
        'created_by' => 1,
        'updated_by' => 1,
        'deleted_by' => NULL,
    ];
}
```

##### Error I am getting

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'deleted_by' cannot be null")

I don't know why it is not letting me set the default value to `null` when I'm setting the field as nullable.

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but what happens if you do `$table->foreignId('deleted_by')->references('id')->on('users')->constrained()->nullable();`?

Comment: Give me out the same error, thought "constrained()" has to come after "nullable()". Very odd why its not working

Comment: $table->foreignId('deleted_by')->nullable()->constrained('users', 'id'); - Had another go at trying to get it working today, this done the trick

Comment: nice! I will take notes